# FormView setting context for form_invalid

Tags: django, formview

I am trying to assign a value to the context if the form is invalid. This is what I am doing. However incase the form is invalid my response is weird and I do not get a form.

```
{'key': 'Val', 'form': <MainLoginForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(user_name;user_category;user_password)>, u'view': <mainApp.views.MainLoginFormView object at 0x107553c10>}  Submit
```

This is the class

```
class MainLoginFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    form_class = MainLoginForm
    success_url = "login.hrml"
    args = {}

    def ValidateAccount(self,form):
        if(valid) #Some Condition to confirm if valid form 
            return super(MainLoginFormView, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)


    def form_invalid(self, form):
        MainLoginFormView.args = super(MainLoginFormView, self).get_context_data(**MainLoginFormView.args)
        MainLoginFormView.args["key"] = "Val"
        MainLoginFormView.args["form"] = form
        #return self.render_to_response(context=MainLoginFormView.args)
        return super(MainLoginFormView,self).form_invalid(MainLoginFormView.args)

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        MainLoginFormView.args = kwargs
        .....
        return self.ValidateAccount(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

`form_invalid` method only takes form as input. You can override it to satisfy your requirements like this:

You should rename args to kwargs

```
def form_invalid(self, form):   
    # Do your your stuff here , 
    MainLoginFormView.kargs["key"] = "Val"
    MainLoginFormView.kargs["form"] = form
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(**MainLoginFormView.kargs))
```